# Flutter project will not run on Android Studio after moving folders

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I'm using Android Studio.

I had a Flutter project on `folder-a`. I moved the contents of `folder-a` into `folder-b` and now...

- The `Tools -> AVD Manager` option is gone.
- The `devices` dropdown is gone on the top bar.
- The `run` button on the top bar is disabled.

What happened and how can I fix it? I heard there is an `import project` option but now that I moved the folders already, I cannot import from the current location. Also, I would like to understand why my project does not work after moving folders.

Comment: Try opening the android folder within the flutter project with Android Studio. You're likely to get more details of why that's happening if you open the android folder via Android Studio.

Comment: As @Rick said, it's likely that Android studio hasn't synced and recognised that there is an Android project present. Make sure to pay attention to the bottom bar of Android studio when doing what was suggested. You should be able to see the process.

Comment: I have the same issue , https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2159 does not apply as module type is JAVA_MODULE, but still no AVD Manager nor LogCat