# why LogCat and AVD Manager missing in Android Studio when flutter project is opened

Tags: android-studio, flutter

In Android Studio 3.5.3 , the menu Tools->AVD Manager and View->Tools Windows->Logcat is not available when a newly(or existing) flutter project is opened.

I looked at https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2159 , and

```
<module type="JAVA_MODULE" version="4">
```

is in the outer most iml file.

Please suggest how to find/enable it. For now I have to open an Android project to open these two menu items.

Comment: there is a similar question but not exactly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59672551

Comment: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/2724

Comment: Flutter use Run tab to display logs in Android Studio. Switch from Logcat to Run and then you will see logs.

Answer (score 2):

LogCat won't appear for a flutter project and does not seem to be available to enable in the current version of Android Studio. If you open an Android project in another window, THAT window will have LogCat which can be connected to the device you are trying to debug.

AVD Manager does not have a menu item in Flutter but is available from an icon in the toolbar. See picture.

[image: AVD Manager]

It's also worth checking out DevTools, which opens up in the browser, as an additional (not LogCat) debugging resource. The button to this is found in the Run Window when you are running an app.

[image]

Comment: Have you opened an Android project in a new window? Just create a new blank Android project. LogCat will be in the new window ONLY but it will be connected to the same Android devices that your Flutter project is connected to. At this time Flutter projects use the Run window as their primary logging view.

Comment: I also open a Android project in new window and see LogCat there, but that seems unnecessary , the flutter project should still be able to show the Logcat, but anyway

Answer (score 0):

There two ways to find or unable it

```
1. Go to the View-> Tool Windows and you can choose whatever you want to put in Tool WindowBar

2. Go to the View-> And Tick or select on Tool Window Bars
```

After doing that you can see the logs for particular apps, And for `AVD manager`...

```
Go to the Tools-> AVD Manager
```